# How to Convert Print Document to PDF

Tags: c#, printing, pdf-generation, xps

I need to convert my print document to pdf.

i used the following code to save it as xps document.how can i generate this to pdf?

```
   PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
                pd = PreparePrintDocument();
                pd.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
                pd.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = "backup.xps";
                pd.Print();
```

Comment: With a third party library like ghost script, which makes this question not really a good fit for this site

Comment: You either need to have a PDF printer installed, or you have to use a third-party library if you don't have your own.